# Pass id from anchor tag dynamically from foreach loop to jquery applying for only one row, i am not able to get popup for the other rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
foreach($subspec as $val) {
    <a id="$val->id"></a>
}
```

Not able to pass the id to trigger an event for particular id

```
<script>
    $('#$val->id').editable({
        type: 'text',
        pk: 1,
        name: 'username',
        url: 'post.php',
        title: 'Enter username'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? we need more information about the desired effect

Comment: i am trying to do inline edit so that for particular subspecification value i need to pass the id to trigger an event but it is applying for only first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php is not valid and you will probably want a class to initialize the editable.

```
<?php foreach($subspec as $val): ?>
    <a id="<?php echo $val->id ?>" class="editable"></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script>
    $('.editable').editable({
        type: 'text',
        pk: 1,
        name: 'username',
        url: 'post.php',
        title: 'Enter username'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am getting this error $('#<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message: Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: views/compareresult2.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 478</p>
</div>').editable({
type: 'text',
pk: 1,
name: 'username',
url: 'post.php',
title: 'Enter username'
});

Answer (score 0):

Why not use classes? when working with multiple elements of the same type it is a much better idea to refer to them as a common class.

```
<?php foreach($subspec as $val)
{
   <a class="editable" id="'echo $val->id'"></a>
}
?>

<script>
    $('.editable').editable({
        type: 'text',
        pk: 1,
        name: 'username',
        url: 'post.php',
        title: 'Enter username'
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
foreach($subspec as $val) {
    echo '<a id="'.$val->id.'"></a>';
}
```

And

```
$('#<?php echo $val->id; ?>').editable({//this should also be in the loop
```